# Symfony Form ManyToOne need empthy

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have form where I add Developer, developer have relationship ManyToOne with entity Teams and in form I can do selecet team for developer, but I would like to have a possibility create developer without teams how can I do this? I need developer without teams, because Developer who have teams have role = ROLE_DEVELOPER, developer who have not teams have role = ROLE_FREELANCER
this is my logic:

```
            if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $team_field = $data->getTeams();

            $pass = $this->hf->generatePassword();
            $entity->setPassword(sha1($pass));
            $entity->setAddedBy($this->getUser());
            if(!empty($team_field)){
                $entity->setRoles('ROLE_DEVELOPER');
            }
            if(empty($team_field)){
                $entity->setRoles('ROLE_FREELANCER');
            }
```

but I need empty($team_field)

this entity developer

```
class Developer extends CustomUser
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255,  unique=false, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 */
protected $email;
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Teams", inversedBy="developers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
protected $teams;
```

this entity Teams

```
class Teams extends STeam
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Developer", mappedBy="teams",  cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $developers;
```

and this form

```
                            ->add('teams', 'entity', array(
                            'class' => 'ArtelProfileBundle:Teams',
                            'property' => 'company',
                            'required' => 'false',
                        ));
```

Help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this  (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#placeholder and http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#empty-data)

```
->add('teams', 'entity', array(
           'class' => 'ArtelProfileBundle:Teams',
           'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
           'empty_data' => null,
           'property' => 'company',
           'required' => 'false'
));
```

If the user does not select anything it will submit with null value.

Comment: exactly, thnks, but if select teams how to re-select the empty field?

Comment: you should be able to see the empty field, as the first option.